# Complexity of the word break algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

My Q is similar to the one asked on stack overflow in the past
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-32-word-break-problem/

The solution I wrote, I am not able to understand that since I do not use DP but still how is it that my sol is solving overlapping problems. I think it is not. Can someone clarify?
my dicitonary that i use is {"cat", "catdog", "dog", "mouse"} and test string as "catdogmouse"
Here is the method i wrote

```
public static boolean recursiveWordBreak2(String s, int start) {
    System.out.println("s is:"+s.substring(start));
    if (s.isEmpty() || start >= s.length()) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = start; i <= s.length(); i++) {
        String str = s.substring(start, i);
        System.out.println("substr:" + str);
        if (dictSet.contains(str)) {
            return recursiveWordBreak2(s, i);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How do you conclude that you're "solving overlapping problems"?  Show the tracing output that exhibits the problem.   [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution uses recursion -only-. recognising that that problem is DP allows you to MEMOIZE (remember) previous results so that you can reuse them without doing the recursion again.

in the link you provided if the dictionary is {a,b,c,d,e} and the input is "abcde", you would need to check if "cde" is valid twice with recursive code, where a DP solution would remember "cde" is valid and only have to check once.

edit: dictionary {a,b,c,d,e} should be {a, ab, cde} to illustrate checking 'cde' twice

edit2 (see comment on algo having logic issue):

```
if (dictSet.contains(str)) {
return recursiveWordBreak2(s, i);  
}
```

should be

```
if (dictSet.contains(str) && recursiveWordBreak2(s, i)) { return true }
```

that way if contains = true but recursiveWB = false, the outer loop will continue to check length+1 instead of returning false

Comment: in my code if what you suggest is happening, why don't i see the substring printed more than once. The substgrin "cde" should be printed more than once. I have the print statements. So either my algo is wrong? or i do not need memoization in this one and it is already optimized? i am not able to see where is the repetition happening as i do not see any substring being repeated in output when i print(see the print statements in code)

Comment: try dictionary = {a, ab, cde}. i think your algo never tries to match 'ab'

Comment: so now i get what you are implying, i do not see overlapping problems in my algo because i am not even going over all sub problems and hence for the case you gave, i get the output as false. Not to be greedy, but can you suggest a small tweak that can fix the algo? You found a good point.

Comment: the pseudo code in your link actually has the solution provided, i've reproduced it here

Comment: thanks, where is the link where u reproduced it? don't see it in ur post the link u r talking abt

Comment: oh got it what you meant. And i also got what was the issue with my code. thanks